# How to correctly catch an exception raised by a module?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In a python project I use a module [python-mpd2](https://github.com/Mic92/python-mpd2) that connects to an (mpd.)server. The server closes the connection after one minute. Most methods provided by the module would then result in an `mpd.ConnectionError`.

I try to build a wrapper class that tries to execute the method but reconnects to the server in case of a previous disconnect.

What I have is this:

```
from mpd import MPDClient, MPDError

class MPDProxy:
    def __init__(self, host="localhost", port=6600, timeout=10):
        self.client = MPDClient()
        self.host = host
        self.port = port

        self.client.timeout = timeout
        self.connect(host, port)

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return self._call_with_reconnect(getattr(self.client, name))

    def connect(self, host, port):
        self.client.connect(host, port)
        self.client.consume(1) # when we call self.client.next() the previous stream is deleted from the playlist
        if len(self.client.playlist()) > 1:
            cur =  (self.client.playlist()[0][6:])
            self.client.clear()
            self.add(cur)

    def _call_with_reconnect(self, func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            except ConnectionError:
                self.connect(self.host, self.port)
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper

mpd_proxy = MPDProxy()
```

However, the `ConnectionError` would not be caught.

```
>>> from MPDProxy import mpd_proxy
>>> mpd_proxy.play()
>>> mpd_proxy.stop()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "./MPDProxy.py", line 26, in wrapper
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/mpd.py", line 588, in decorator
    return wrapper(self, name, args, bound_decorator(self, returnValue))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/mpd.py", line 229, in _execute
    return retval()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/mpd.py", line 583, in decorator
    return function(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/mpd.py", line 352, in _fetch_nothing
    line = self._read_line()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/mpd.py", line 260, in _read_line
    raise ConnectionError("Connection lost while reading line")
mpd.ConnectionError: Connection lost while reading line
```

How would I correctly catch the ConnectionError?

Comment: I don't see `decorator` anywhere in your code.

Comment: can you expand on this? I know there is the error message that mentions the decorator, but I don't use it in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: Try importing `mpd` module in your code.

```
import mpd
```

And then change the line:

```
except ConnectionError
```

by

```
except mpd.ConnectionError
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you be more precise? and are you sure? because if I use `except:` instead of `except ConnectionError` it works.

Comment: Ahh, ok, try: `except mpd.ConnectionError` That's the correct exception according your error message.

Comment: Try one of the variants I posted in the answer and let me know about results.

Comment: I think this could work... however I wonder if it wasn't possible to import just the important parts of mpd (not the whole module)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47529/discussion-between-raydel-miranda-and-speendo)

Comment: Python imports are not like `#include` directives in C; it is no skin off of your back to import the module, and it's generally better practice to.

Answer (score 3):

you need something like the following:

```
 def connect(self):
    try:
        self.client.connect(self._host, self._port)
    # Catch socket errors
    except IOError as err:
        errno, strerror = err
        raise PollerError("Could not connect to '%s': %s" %
                          (self._host, strerror))

    # Catch all other possible errors
    # ConnectionError and ProtocolError are always fatal.  Others may not
    # be, but we don't know how to handle them here, so treat them as if
    # they are instead of ignoring them.
    except MPDError as e:
        raise PollerError("Could not connect to '%s': %s" %
                          (self._host, e))
```

For more info on this look at the examples under [Documentation](https://github.com/Mic92/python-mpd2#documentation)
Also, according to your error message the correct error to catch for `ConnectionError` is `mdp.ConnectionError`. ConnectionError is an exception defined by mdp.

Answer (score 1):

Import the exception type, or rather, import the whole dang module and refer to the exception via its module. **Don't just catch all exceptions!** You will catch things you didn't mean to and you will have silent failures.

```
import mpd
# alternatively, from mpd import ConnectionError

try:
    # your code here
except mpd.ConnectionError as mpdece:
    # handle that exception!
```

It's preferable to import the module because, hypothetically, say two modules you import have something called `ConnectionError`. You might shadow one `ConnectionError` with the other.

If you are importing a module with a long name, you can do `import module_with_long_name as mwln` etc.